# How to use gpfdist to load data directly into a db instead of a file

Tags: greenplum

This question is specified for pivotal greenplum. I was told that gpfdist can load data from memory(not files) directly into greenplum. Is there anymore know that and how?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post on this subject.  http://www.pivotalguru.com/?p=871

More documentation here: http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4360/admin_guide/load/topics/g-write-the-gpfdist-configuration.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the answer doesn't answer my question. My question is load data from memory(not files) into greenlum using gpfdist.

Comment: What application or database that is in-memory are you trying to read with gpfdist?

Comment: I am trying to load the some tables in gemfirexd into greenplum using gpfdist.

Comment: Then the options listed here all work.  You can use TRANSFORM as in the blog post or a named pipe.  Lastly, you can skip gpfdist and use the client directly by invoking with an External Web Table.

Answer (score 0):

gpfdist can read from a named pipe.

Alternatively you can use SpringXD to stream data and use gpfdist as a sink.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#gpfdist

Answer (score 0):

EXTERNAL WEB TABLE is good option for this situation.
For Example if you want get disk usage of all segment servers.

First Create EXTERNAL TABLE

```
CREATE EXTERNAL WEB TABLE disk_free (
dfsegment integer,
dfhostname text,
dfdevice text,
dfused bigint,
dfavail bigint) EXECUTE E'python -c "from gppylib.commands import unix; df=unix.DiskFree.get_disk_free_info_local(\'token\',\'$GP_SEG_DATADIR\'); print \'%s, %s, %s, %s, %s\' % (\'$GP_SEGMENT_ID\', unix.getLocalHostname(), df[0], df[2], df[3])"' ON ALL FORMAT 'csv' (delimiter E',' null E'' escape E'"' quote E'"')ENCODING 'UTF8';
```

This EXTERNAL TABLE will give result like below

```
 testdb=# SELECT * FROM disk_free ;
 dfsegment | dfhostname |          dfdevice           | dfused  | dfavail
-----------+------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------
         0 |  sdw1      |  /dev/mapper/vg_mdw-lv_root | 5363352 | 16197044
         1 |  sdw2      |  /dev/mapper/vg_mdw-lv_root | 6130012 | 15430384
         3 |  sdw4      |  /dev/mapper/vg_mdw-lv_root | 5363752 | 16196644
         2 |  sdw3      |  /dev/mapper/vg_mdw-lv_root | 6140312 | 15420084
```